# install Ubuntu Openstack Autopilot on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: openstack-autopilot

I'm trying to install Ubuntu Openstack Autopilot using a IBM System x3560 M4 where is installed as Hypervisor VMware ESXi 6. I've installed MAAS with one vnet (mngmt), deployed 6 vnode for Autopilot:

- 1 VM for Landscape;
- 5 VM for Openstack;

[image]

as suggested from its web page we need to run the following command

**`$: sudo JUJU_BOOTSTRAP_TO=<Landscape> openstack-install`**

the deploy begin the procedure

[image]

[image]
but after long time receive the following error

[image]

the command.log file reports that 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23322431/

checking the log on the node where autopilot is making the deploy I've that

[image]

I open a issue here:

[here](https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/1021)

Update: 
I've found also that suggest (before last post)

[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/870018/ubuntu-openstack-autopilot-install-failing#comment1348416_870018)

I've followed that but the deploy of Openstack is stopped at 78% without error and it's not continue:

[image]
[image]

anyone can help me? thanks in advance

Comment: Please file the bug as directed  - at https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues

Comment: @Adam its support told me the the error is of MAAS