# Ubuntu OpenStack Autopilot Install Failing

Tags: juju, maas, python-2.7, landscape, openstack-autopilot

I am following the steps outlined on the [Get OpenStack Autopilot](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud) page. I've already deployed MAAS 1.9 on Ubuntu 14.04LTS and have 5 nodes in the Ready state in MAAS. However, when I run openstack-install on the MAAS box the juju bootstrap phase is failing with TLS errors at the point of trying to deploy Landscape on one of the MAAS nodes. See this issue on the Ubuntu Solutions Engineering github page [Error deploying Landscape](https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/1030) for detailed error logs for ~/.cloud-install/*.log on the MAAS box and /var/log/juju/all-machines.log on the deployed node.

```
http: TLS handshake error from 10.14.0.1:37540: tls: client offered an unsupported, maximum protocol version of 301
```

It's been identified that a recent update of python has caused this incompatibility since the juju deployer dropped TLS 1.0 support.

> "For security concerns we've removed TLS 1.0 support from Juju in the
>   1.25 release cycle. The default python 2.7 in Trusty does not support TLS 1.2. You need to update Python in order to have this work
>   correctly on Trusty."

see Richard Harding's comment on [juju-deployer failed on SSL3_READ_BYTES](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-deployer/+bug/1644331)

See this github issue on the Ubuntu Solutions Engineering: [Getting install error on juju bootstrap after python update](https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/issues/1017).

It's stated in that issue that it's waiting on addressing the python issue here [Support for TLS 1.2 not present (added in 2.7.9)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python2.7/+bug/1443704).

How can I move forward in this situation?

Comment: The version of python on my MAAS machine is currently 2.7.6. I'm going to try installing v2.7.9 on the MAAS machine and report back the results.

Comment: updating MAAS to python v2.7.9 did not resolve the issue, still experienced the same error. The way I updated python was downloading the source, .configure, make, sudo make install and rebooting. python --version reports 2.7.9. The error is surfacing in the logs of the deployed server for landscape. See /var/log/juju/machine-0.log here: http://pastebin.com/xuEJGf9q

Comment: I'm going to try updating python to 2.7.9 on the deployed node and try to restart the install.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't update the deployed node and re-run the openstack-installer. It first requires that you run sudo openstack-install -u which will uninstall it on the MAAS node, and it "destroys" the node in MAAS, basically moves it back to Ready from Deployed. Therefore, the next time you run sudo openstack-install it will create the node again from scratch.

Comment: My workaround, at the moment, was to deploy an Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty server through MAAS and manually install Landscape on the machine following the steps found here: https://landscape.canonical.com/set-up-on-prem. After doing that, I was able to log into the Landscape UI and configure my MAAS server and initiate the OpenStack deployment which is at 74% at the moment. All physical servers have spun up.

Comment: The workaround currently isn't working either. It's getting stuck at 76% with the error ERROR oslo.messaging._drivers.impl_rabbit [-] AMQP server on 127.0.0.1:5672 is unreachable: [Errno 111] ECONNREFUSED. Googled this one over and over without finding a solution

Comment: same problem it's stuck at 79%. any suggest?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue and never could figure out why. I ended up doing a manual juju boot strap and then deploy the juju-gui. Then deploying landscape on top of that(I used 14.04 LTS).

Creating environments.yaml

Create or modify ~/.juju/environments.yaml with the following content:

```
environments:
  maas:
    type: maas
    maas-server: 'http://${my-maas-server}:80/MAAS'
    maas-oauth: '${maas-api-key}'
    admin-secret: ${your-admin-secret}
    default-series: trusty
```

Now deploy juju:

```
$ sudo apt-get install juju-core
$ juju bootstrap --upload-tools
$ juju status
```

Now once the juju bootstrapped node had finished deploy the juju-gui

```
$ juju deploy juju-gui
$ juju expose juju-gui
```

To keep track of the progress of the gui keep checking 'juju status' or run 'watch juju staus'. When it is done you will see something like:

[image]

Then you can enter that IP into your browser to access the juju gui. After that on the juju going search for the landscape bundle and deploy.